# Algorithm for leader election in synchronous ring with a known network size $n$ with phases of length $\frac{n}{m}$

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, distributed-systems

Consider the following leader election algorithm election of a synchronous ring with a known network size $n$ (simultaneous wakeup and uni-directional communication):

- The leader is the node with the minimal ID
- The algorithm works in phase - each phase is of length $n$
- in the $i$th phase, only the node with $ID=i$ is allowed to initiate communication
- the message he sends is $1$ bit message
- all other nodes only relay the message, and conclude the ID of the leader based on the time

The algorithm has time complexity of $O(k\cdot n)$ (where $k$ is the minimal ID in the network) and sends $O(n)$ bits.

Now, I want to devise a version of this algorithm with phases of length $\frac{n}{m}$ for an integer $m$.

The complexities are allowed to be $O(\frac{kn}{m})$ for time, and $O(nm\log n)$ for the amount of bits.

MY idea is pretty similar to the original algorithm.

- The leader is the node with the minimal ID
- The algorithm works in phase - each phase is of length $\frac{n}{m}$
- in the $i$th phase, only the node with $ID=i$ is allowed to initiate communication
- the message he sends is it's ID in bit representation
- all other nodes only relay a message with the minimal ID they've seen so far
- if a node receives its own ID - he knows it's the leader

From my analysis:

The time complexity is $(k-1) \cdot \frac{n}{m} + n$ and the message complexity does get to the needed $O(nm\log n)$. This is because the minimal ID is sent $n$ times, the second smallest ID is sent $\frac{(m-1)n}{m}$ times, and so on. We get the series: $\frac{(m-1)n}{m} + \ldotp \ldotp \ldotp + \frac{n}{m} = O(nm)$. Since each message is $O(\log n)$ bits, we get the correct complexity.

Is my analysis correct? I'm not sure about the time complexity.

Help would be appreciated.